# Estimating the number of binary words with few $0$s

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $B_n$ be the binary strings in $\{0,1\}^n$ containing at most $n/3$ zeros. Then the size is
$$|B_n| = \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/3\rfloor} {n \choose i}$$
However, is there a simple way to estimate the size of $|B_n|$ which is strong enough to imply
$$\frac{|B_n|}{2^n} \rightarrow 0$$
(I don't see a nice estimate for the above sum, maybe I missing something obvious!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to estimate sums like this. In fact, for any fixed fraction $\alpha<\frac{1}{2}$ we have $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i=0}^{\alpha n} \binom{n}{i}=0$$

It could be proved by bounding the sum from above by the largest term multiplied by the number of terms (and then fiddling with the asymptotics), but it also follows easily from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Bounds_and_asymptotic_formulas)'s upper bound in terms of binary entropy:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\alpha n} \binom{n}{i} \leq 2^{-(\alpha\log_2 \alpha+(1-\alpha)\log_2 (1-\alpha))n}$$

For example, for $\alpha=\frac{1}{3}$, the sum grows somewhat slower than $1.89^n$.